# best way to call ajax after input validation loop

Tags: jquery, ajax

I seem to be stuck at this piece.  I'm looking for a nice clean way of looping through inputs for empty.  But if all pass as not being empty, do an ajax call.

```
$("#save-material").click(function(){
    $('#material input').each(function(){
        if(!$(this).val()){
            //alert('fields are empty');
            $(this).parent('td').addClass('error');


        }else{
            $(this).parent('td').removeClass('error');
            $(this).parent('td').addClass('success');

        }//END OF ELSE
    });//END OF .EACH
        inputs = $('#material').serialize();
        //get job ID
        uri = window.location.href;
        parts = uri.split('/');
        ID = parts[5].match(/id=(.*)/);
        //make the ajax call
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '../../assets/php/addmaterials.php?'+ID[1],
            data: inputs,
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
    });//END OF AJAX
});//END OF save-material function
```

Comment: Is this question still outstanding? If yes, please provide more details so we can help you solve it. If resolved, please close the question by (a) selecting a correct answer, or (b) providing your own answer and marking it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're missing the check to count the `.success` table cells.

```
var count = $('#material .success').length;
if (count > 5) {
    // do ajax stuff
}
```

Does your loop work? Are you getting the success class added?

Comment: this was quick, easy.  Thanks Jeff.  I can't vote you apparently I'm too newby.  'Vote Up requires 15 reputation'

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach. First, I add `success` class to all textboxes. Then, using `filter` I retrieve the textboxes that are empty, and bind them to the array called `a`. If the `length` of the array is bigger than zero, the form is invalid. I add `error` class to these empty fields by using `a` array shortly. Hope this makes sense.

```
$('input:button').click(function () {    
     $('#apply-form input').addClass('success').removeClass('error');
     var a = $('#apply-form input').filter(function (i) {
        return this.value.length == 0;
     });

    a.addClass('error');
    if (a.length) {
       alert('empty field');
    } else {
       //call ajax
       alert('valid');
    }
 });
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/erkaner/avun1d2k/2/

Answer (score 0):

Simple example - just alerts error and aborts routine.

```
$("#save-material").click(function(){
    var isErr = false; // <====== addition
    $('#material input').each(function(){
        if(!$(this).val()){
            isErr = true; // <====== addition
            //alert('fields are empty');
            $(this).parent('td').addClass('error');
        }else{
            $(this).parent('td').removeClass('error');
            $(this).parent('td').addClass('success');
        }//END OF ELSE
    });//END OF .EACH

    if (isErr) { // <====== addition
        alert('Please complete all fields');
        return false;
    }

    inputs = $('#material').serialize();
    //get job ID
    uri = window.location.href;
    parts = uri.split('/');
    ID = parts[5].match(/id=(.*)/);
    //make the ajax call
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '../../assets/php/addmaterials.php?'+ID[1],
        data: inputs,
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(data){
            alert(data);
        }
    });//END OF AJAX
});//END OF save-material function
```